# styling the nav-items to have full background width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar in bootstrap and I am trying to design the navbar-item to have background color but when I try to do that there are still some spaces which doesn't take up that background color. How can I make it cover the whole screen?

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-collapse li a {
    /* style goes here */
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="images/brand.jpeg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> El Credor </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product1</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product2</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product3</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product4</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product5</span></a> </li>
      </ul> <a id="aboutUsRemove" class="navbar-brand aboutUs" href="#"> About Us </a> </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .navbar has padding of `1rem` so you'd need to counteract that on the `nav-link`s

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    /* style goes here */
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: -1rem;
    margin-right: -1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/dp3YZWMLWy

Comment: this is not what I wanted. I wanted to change the color only for the `nav-items` not the whole navbar.

Comment: it also said `nav-items` on the question. Anyway sorry about that bro. I have changed it.

Comment: the changing of width can be clearly screen. Is there any way to remove that?

Comment: The only way to be to override the normal `.collapsing` animation using the `.fade` class.. `"collapse navbar-collapse fade"`

Comment: I don't understand. You mean to say to add `fade` class to that `.collapsing`?

Comment: Yes. Look at the demo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background of links you can do it in this way.

**snippet**

```css
 @media (max-width: 992px) {
  .nav-link > span {
    /* style goes here */
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="images/brand.jpeg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> El Credor </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product1</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product2</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product3</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product4</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>product5</span></a> </li>
      </ul> <a id="aboutUsRemove" class="navbar-brand aboutUs" href="#"> About Us </a> </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!